# Getting multiple inputs in C++ simultaneously using kbhit() function

Tags: c++, game-mechanics, game-loop

I am using Turbo C++ to make a game using the `graphics.h` library (I know it's a bit old). In this game, the player can move left, right and they can jump using *A*, *D* and *W* (just like in Super Mario).

I am using the `kbhit()` function to get inputs from user. The problem with it is that I cannot jump and move the character at the same time (so it moves in a parabolic trajectory).
How can I take multiple inputs so that, for example, if I press *W* **and** *D*, character will jump towards right?

The code is given below:

```
if(kbhit())
{
    ch=getch();

    if(ch=='e'){break;}   //exit

    if(ch=='d')           //move right
    {
    ax=1;
    if(vx<vellim){vx=vx+ax*dt;}
    dx=vx*dt;
    x+=dx;
    s_mario(x,y); //This function draws the character at the appropriate place

    }

    if(ch=='a')             //move left
    {
    ax=-1;
    if(vx>-vellim){vx=vx+ax*dt;}
    dx=vx*dt;
    x+=dx;
    s_mario(x,y);
    }

    if(ch=='w'&&jumpkey==0)   //jump
    {
    vy=60;
    jumpkey=1;
    }

}

if(jumpkey==1)
{
vy=vy-g;
dy=vy*dt;
y-=dy*0.1;
if(y>400){y=399;vy=0;jumpkey=0;}
s_mario(x,y);

}

if(!kbhit())
{       vx*=c;
    dx=vx*dt;
    x+=dx;
    s_mario(x,y);
    delay(5);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `getch()` is used for key presses, but what you want is separate key down and key up events (or as KevLoughrey says, a function that tells you the key state). See more discussion [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40961527/checking-if-a-key-is-down-in-ms-dos-c-c) with sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Console I/O wasn't designed for this kind of thing. You'll need a different means of handling input.

Google suggests that the `GetAsyncKeyState()` is what you're looking for:

Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx

Example usage: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/135868/#msg725863